# How can I set a value for TextBox.FontFamily property?

Tags: wpf

I am trying to learn WPF, the problem is I need to learn XAML first. In System.Windows.Controls.TextBox class, there is property 'FontFamily'. I will have to set a font for it. In one of my book I saw  But where can I get this font(Verdana). Where is list of all font's in MSDN Library?

Ikbal Hassan

Comment: What are you having a problem with? Setting the property, or knowing which fonts will be available on the user's computer? Verdana should be included with the OS on any version of Windows that can run WPF.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the string name of the font as shown below as font.Name. The following code is loading up a ComboBox of all the fonts.

```
var installedfonts = new InstalledFontCollection();
int idFont = 0;
foreach ( var font in installedfonts.Families )
{
    var fonttype = new LookupSelectItem { Id = idFont, Name = font.Name };
                            FontTypeList.Add( fonttype );
                            ++ idFont;
}
```